# Weak formulation incompressible Euler equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A divergence-free vector field $v \in L_{loc}^2(\mathbb{R}^n_{x}\times \mathbb{R}_{t},\mathbb{R}^n)$ is said to be a weak solution of the incompressible Euler equation 
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + div(v \otimes v) + \nabla p = 0\\
div(v) =0$$
if 
$$ \int v \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + (v \otimes v) \cdot \nabla \phi \: dx dt = 0\\
\int v \cdot \nabla \phi \: dx dt = 0$$
are satisfied for every divergence-free $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n_{x}\times \mathbb{R}_{t},\mathbb{R}^n)$. To achieve this we first have to multiply by $\phi$ and then integrate in space and time. Then by integration by parts we get
$$\int \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \cdot \phi - (v \otimes v)\cdot \nabla \phi + \nabla p \cdot \phi \: dx dt = 0 \\
\int v \cdot \nabla \phi \: dx dt = 0$$
But I don't understand how the rest transforms. As $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n_{x}\times \mathbb{R}_{t}$ we can write $\Omega = \Omega_x \times I$ for some Interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}_{t}$. So I think with weak derivation we can get  $$\int_{\Omega_{x}} \int_{t} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \cdot \phi \: dt dx = -\int_{\Omega_{x}} \int_{t} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \cdot v \: dt dx$$
I would transform the $\nabla p \cdot \phi$ term in the same way but I read somewhere that the pressure $p$ disappears because $v$ is incompressible. Could someone explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that one can write the pressure $p$ in a form where it only depends on the velocity $v$. To get the form we need we take the divergence of the Euler equation
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} div(v) + div(\nabla v \cdot v) + div(\nabla p) = 0$$
Because $div(v)=0$ for an incompressible fluid and $div(\nabla p) = \Delta p$, it can be transformed to
$$ 0= div(\nabla v) \cdot v + tr(\nabla v \cdot \nabla v) + \Delta p = \nabla(div(v)) \cdot v + tr(\nabla v \cdot \nabla v) + \Delta p $$
As $div(v)=0$ we then get
$$\Delta p = - tr(\nabla v \cdot \nabla v)$$
So I assume that it is sufficient to find a weak soultion $v$ to the weak formulation above (with eliminated pressure) and to find then an associated pressure in a weak
sense.

Answer (score -1):

I recently read the paper 'The Euler equations as a differential inclusion' by De Lellis and Szekelyhidi and found the possible answer on the next line of the second formula in it (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702079.pdf).

Indeed, the authors chose test functions satisfy the condition that $$\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}_t,\mathbb{R}^n),\ div \varphi = 0,$$
then the $\nabla p\cdot \varphi$ term disappears since $\varphi$ is incompressible, thanks to the integration by parts
$$ \int \nabla p\cdot \varphi\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t = -\int p\cdot (div\varphi)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t = 0.$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).